# Upload video to Facebook page with Graph API - RestFB

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token, restfb

I've been trying to upload a video to my FB page using the Graph API through RestFB Java library. I am having an issue with the access token when accessing it through the Graph API explorer. To publish video it says my application needs review from FB but I only want to post to my own page. Where can I get an access token that allows publishing to my page without having to submit a review?

Thanks

Comment: are you selecting YOUR app in the api explorer, and not just the api explorer app? btw, i believe without review posting is possible, but the posts will not be visible to other users. so there is probably no way around review.

Comment: There is only my app in the drop down list. It seems the API explorer app was deprecated earlier this year. Actually I wouldn't mind if it wasn't visible to others. I just want to it visible to me. Quite confused.

Comment: your the admin of the app and the page, then give it a try. If there is a red banner on the facebook login during access token generation simply ignore it. Only if you run into OAuthExceptions there is a problem.

Comment: @Norbert I am running into OAuthException (#100) error. Even though my access token shows the right permissions in the debugger.

Comment: what's the error message, 100 says nothing special ;)